# Python: How to affix the values of another df's columns to current df col names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have original df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Creatinine':[68,69,80,75],
                  'Ferritin':[251,1481,107,110],
                  'ALT':[11,14,10,15]})
```

[image]

I would like to add the values of df2 (below) as a suffix to the col names of df respectively.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Creatinine_Units':['umol/L','umol/L','umol/L','umol/L'],
                  'Ferritin_units':['ug/L','ug/L','ug/L','ug/L'],
                  'ALT':['U/L','U/L','U/L','U/L']})
```

[image]

Expected Outcome:

[image]

How do I go about this in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform arithmetic on column names like this:

```
df.columns = df.columns + ' (' + df2.iloc[0] + ')'
```

Output:

```
   Creatinine (umol/L)  Ferritin (ug/L)  ALT (U/L)
0                   68              251         11
1                   69             1481         14
2                   80              107         10
3                   75              110         15
```